# Creating a unique ID for a column variable

Tags: r, uniqueidentifier, unique-id

I'm trying to create a unique variable which corresponds to companies in a panel dataset. I'm using R.

Currently the data looks like this:

| investor | year | activity | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 IM | 2002 | 4.45 | France |
| 123 IM | 2003 | 3.2 | France |
| 123 IM | 2004 | 7.8 | France |
| Aegon | 2005 | 5.4 | Netherlands |
| Aegon | 2006 | 4.2 | Netherlands |
| Aegon | 2007 | 1.3 | Netherlands |

I would like to create a new column so the dataframe looks like this:

| investor | investorid | year | activity | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 IM | 1 | 2002 | 4.45 | France |
| 123 IM | 1 | 2003 | 3.2 | France |
| 123 IM | 1 | 2004 | 7.8 | France |
| Aegon | 2 | 2005 | 5.4 | Netherlands |
| Aegon | 2 | 2006 | 4.2 | Netherlands |
| Aegon | 2 | 2007 | 1.3 | Netherlands |

The exact location of the column doesn't really matter, I just put it next to the investor name in this example.

I expect I need to use grouby(investor) then mutate a new column?

Cheers!

Comment: use `dense_rank()` or `as.numeric(as.factor())`

Comment: or `cumsum(!duplicated(df$investor))`